# iOS Swift - Unable to trigger segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have the below code which shows an alert box when user signs up. After the user interacts with the Alert Box button (i.e. let's go), I have a segue I need triggered (called someSegue for now) so that it can redirect the user to login page.

Nothing is happening after user clicks alert box button. What am I missing? is it the self there? if I remove the self it doesn't work and xcode complains.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (succeeded, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.

                        let delay = 4.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
                        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            actInd.stopAnimating()
                            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Congratulations!", message: "Your account was successfully created! You will be required to login with your credentials.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Let's Go!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someSegue", sender: self)
                        }



                    } else {
                        // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Try calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside         `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {<HERE>})`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a block of code after alert button is pressed you need to pass that block in handler parameter of addAction method

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Let's Go!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someSegue", sender: self)   
    }))
```